# Enable SSL in Spring boot Application

Tags: java, tomcat

How to enable SSL with self signed certificate in a Spring Boot Application, I have added configuration in the property file but didnt worked for me.

Comment: Can you post your application.properties file?

Answer (score 1):

First thing to do is to generate a certificate. You can choose among different formats like [PKCS12](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS_12) or [JKS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_KeyStore). I'll go with PKCS12 as it is a standard format not limited to JVM:

```sh
$keytool -genkeypair -alias so57488831 -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -storetype PKCS12 -keystore so57488831.p12 -validity 365

Enter keystore password: <so57488831>
Re-enter new password: <so57488831>

What is your first and last name?
  [Unknown]:  madhead
What is the name of your organizational unit?
  [Unknown]:  N/A
What is the name of your organization?
  [Unknown]:  N/A
What is the name of your City or Locality?
  [Unknown]:  Minsk
What is the name of your State or Province?
  [Unknown]:  Minsk
What is the two-letter country code for this unit?
  [Unknown]:  BY
Is CN=madhead, OU=N/A, O=N/A, L=Minsk, ST=Minsk, C=BY correct?
  [no]:  yes
```

A file named `so57488831.p12` will be generated. Place it in your project's `resources` directory: `src/main/resources/so57488831.p12`.

[Configure Spring Boot](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-web-servers.html#howto-configure-ssl):

*application.yml:*

```
server:
  ssl:
    key-store-type: PKCS12
    key-store: classpath:so57488831.p12
    key-alias: so57488831
    key-store-password: so57488831
```

You're good to go. Invoke your app via HTTPS:

[image]

See that "untrusted certificate" yellow triangle warning in Firefox? Let's check it out:

[image]

If you're interested, take a look at the [demo project](https://gitlab.com/madhead-playgrounds/so57488831) I've created for this question.

Comment: What changes to be made in the server.xml of Tomcat after this?